# Pine Script label is not showing up

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

So i have a label that wont show up at all. when i compile, there are no errors, and the full script shows up fine, but the label will not appear no matter what.
Are you only allowed to have one label per bar or something?

The specific line of code looks like this:

```
pullback_label = label.new(bar_index, low, color = pullback[1]? #0000FF: na, text = tostring(pullbackp) + "%", textcolor = pullback[1]? #E1E102:na, style=label.style_label_up)
```

where "pullback" is a variable defined earlier in the script.

i want to plot the percent from previous close that todays low got to.

Comment: The code looks fine.  *line.new* has some limitations. [Check this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/writing/Limitations.html?#line-box-and-label-limits)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
If barstate.islast 
    pullback_label = label.new(bar_index, low, color = pullback[1]? #0000FF: na, text = tostring(pullbackp) + "%", textcolor = pullback[1]? #E1E102:na, style=label.style_label_up)
```